# Swift - Is it possible to use ios Mail app attachments icon?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, icons, email-attachments

In my app, I want to use an icon for the uploaded document based on its type. Is it possible to use Mail app attachment type icons?

Answer (score 0):

Your app should bundle up any icon you want to use and not rely on icons supplied as part of another app.  You can get a good graphic designer to generate icons for the different attachment types you want to support, or buy one of the many commercial icon sets on the market.

It is possible to extract the icons from any app; but while technically feasible it is not legally advisable.

Comment: Just curious how it's technically possible?

Comment: @PAC There are lots of sites where you can get free open icons (legally valid to use). BTW you can not use other `app icon` but  simple icon is managable.

Comment: @PAC none that are legally advisable on this site :)